# Parsing a range of integers in a list

Tags: python, regex, parsing, syntax-error

I've just began learning Python and I've ran into a small problem.
I need to parse a text file, more specifically an HTML file (but it's syntax is so weird - divs after divs after divs, the result of a Google's 'View as HTML' for a certain PDF i can't seem to extract the text because it has a messy table done in m$ word).

Anyway, I chose a rather low-level approach because i just need the data asap and since I'm beginning to learn Python, I figured learning the basics would do me some good too.

I've got everything done except for a small part in which i need to retrieve a set of integers from a set of divs. Here's an example:

```
<div style="position:absolute;top:522;left:1020"><nobr>*88</nobr></div>
```

Now the numbers i want to retrieve all the ones inside `<nobr></nobr>` (in that case, '588') and, since it's quite a messy file, i have to make sure that what I am getting is correct. To do so, that number inside `<nobr></nobr>` must be preceded by `"left:1020"`, `"left:1024"` or `"left:1028"`. This is because of the automatic conversion and the best choice would be to get all the number preceded by `left:102[0-]` in my opinion.

To do so, I was trying to use:

```
for o in re.finditer('left:102[0-9]"><nobr>(.*?)</nobr></div>', words[index])
    out = o.group(1)
```

But so far, no such luck... How can I get those numbers?

Thanks in advance,
J.

Comment: Obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I am just checking, but in the line below the data you are digesting you have `(in that case, '588')` but in the line of data what is between `<nobr></nobr>` is `*88`.  I would edit and fix it, but I do not know which is the correct entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML. [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) will make light work of this.

As for your specific problem, it might be that you are missing a colon at the end of the first line:

```
for o in re.finditer('left:102[0-9]"><nobr>(.*?)</nobr></div>', words[index]):
    out = o.group(1)
```

If this isn't the problem, please post the error you are getting, at what you expect the output to be.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard about it but I wasn't sure it would manage to get all those weird divs, hence the low-level approach

Comment: @Hal: BeautifulSoup can find tags based on attributes, and it can even accept regex as arguments for the search if you need that.

Comment: Cool, didn't know it was so powerful. Anyway, I've practically finished the script, all that's missing is getting those integers. I guess I could simply make 10 searches, but that would be plain dumb and I'd like to learn how one could use regex on that string.

Comment: You did it. I wasn't getting any error at all, for some reason the damn thing would just output a blank space.

Thanks for putting up with this noob crap, it's guys like you that make StackOverflow so awesome.